# Spring MVC component Scan does not pick up controller

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

All,

I am trying to setup a new Spring MVC project and have created a dummy controller.
The problem that i am facing is Spring is not creating the bean of the controller. otherwise the logging statement inside the constructor should have printed.
The package of the controller is also defined in the beans configuration xml.

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.apps" annotation-config="true"/>`

Spring Version: 5.2.8
Tomcat Version: 8

There is a specific reason why i am using the above versions and using xml based configuration.

The error that i get is:

```
Aug 25, 2020 10:53:02 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /[app-name]/health
```

which is not surprising considering the bean did not get created.

Please find the code below...

```
package com.blah.apps.xyz.shopping.health;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HealthController {

public HealthController() {
        System.out.println("Event this is not getting printed...the component scan should allow spring bean discovery..");
    }


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/health")
    public String getHealth() {
        return "App is running!";
    }
}
```

My Web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <absolute-ordering />
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- have tried removing annotation-config as well-->

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.blah.apps" annotation-config="true"/> 
</beans>
```

Comment: is dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml : under WEB-INF ?

Comment: Yes. i believe if its not there then the servlet initialization throws FileNotFound Exception.. That was my first clue.. but since that exception is not there, it means it is able to find it

Comment: Make sure that the package is correct AND that the class is actually there when creating the war file.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes I see the generated class files.

Comment: I actually doubt it is. Is it in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder?

Comment: Try adding this to your web xml  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: *a new Spring MVC project* Why are you using the old way of doing things instead of the modern way (Spring Boot)?

Comment: Don't add the `ContextLoaderListener` for loading the same context!. This means you are loading the application twice!.

Comment: right. But you need a root context. You can change name to your xml

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, its inside WEB-INF/classes ..

Comment: No you don't need a root context, only when using filters (like Spring Security) or if you want to sore components between multiple dispatcher servlets.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your project, something which you aren't showing/telling here. Without that missing piece of information I would say this question is impossible to answer. IMHO either your package is wrong (either in your class or XML) or the class or XML file you think is there really isn't.

Comment: If you setup a new Spring MVC, so please do not use deprecated xml configuration. Use https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

Finally figured out what the problem was. The code was all correct... Even though the target folder had the controller class files, eclipse was changing the default output folder to project specific output folder (even though I have not specified anywhere.. not sure why this is hapenning on every build...).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener in your web.xml to load you Spring context.

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are using Spring mvc, you should have a listener i.e. ContextLoaderListener   in your web.xml. Add the below code in your web.xml.

```
 <listener>
      <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
    </listener>
      
    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

DispatcherServlet primary purpose is to handle incoming web requests matching the configured URL pattern. It take an incoming URI and find the right combination of controller and view.

ContextLoaderListener creates the root application context and will be shared with child contexts created by all DispatcherServlet contexts. Its job is to take the Spring configuration files as input and creates the Spring-managed beans as per configuration and make it ready during server startup and destroys them during server shutdown.

If you want to read more about ContectLoaderListener do visit https://www.java67.com/2019/05/contextloaderlistener-in-spring-mvc-10.html.